# Retornar View sem perder os dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um código na minha `controller` que faz alguns procedimentos, se algum desses procedimentos der errado, ele me retorna a `view` que eu desejo e na view eu exibo algumas mensagens, essa minha `view` é uma `view` de formulário.

O que está acontecendo:

Quando eu termino o método na controller eu utilizo `return View();`, mas eles me retorna os campos vazio, ele recarrega toda a página, gostaria que ele voltasse a `view` com os dados que já estavam preenchidos, pensei em usar return `RedirectToAction("Create");` mas acontece a mesma coisa, teria algum tipo de retorno(é necessário ter um retorno no meu método que não recarregasse a página?

Meu código na controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(TipoPecaViewModel ambienteViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TipoPecaModel ambienteModel = new TipoPecaModel();
            ambienteModel.TpPeca_Codigo = ambienteViewModel.TpPeca_Codigo;
            ambienteModel.GrupoProduto_Codigo = ambienteViewModel.GrupoProduto_Codigo;
            ambienteModel.TpPeca_Sigla = ambienteViewModel.TpPeca_Sigla;
            ambienteModel.TpPeca_Situacao = ambienteViewModel.TpPeca_Situacao.Equals(true) ? "A" : "D";
            ambienteModel.usr_cod_criacao = Convert.ToInt16(Services.Token.strCod_Usuario);
            ambienteModel.usr_dt_hr_criacao = DateTime.Now.Date;
            ambienteModel.Emp_codigo = Services.Token.strEmp_codigo;

            var UrlApi = "api/TipoPeca/create";
            Uri BaseAdress = Services.Token.BaseAdress;
            string strToken = Services.Token.strToken;
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = BaseAdress;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strToken);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/Json"));
                var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ambienteModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(UrlApi, stringContent))
                {
                    var teste = (int)response.StatusCode;
                    if(teste == 400){
                        validar2 = "True";
                        return View();
                    }else if(teste == 409){
                        validar2 = "Trues";
                        return View();
                    }
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return Redirect("/TipoPeca/Fechar");
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return View(ambienteViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa retornar igual o seu else, passando o viewmodel de volta para view:

```
return View(ambienteViewModel);
```

Assim a viewmodel continuará preenchido e os campos serão recarregados. Agora se você quer fazer uma chamada assíncrona, pode usar o AJAX e o JQUERY para isso, o Razor dá suporte, mas precisa procurar a documentação referente a versão do MVC que você está usando.

Segue uma referência em MVC 5: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-razor-ajax-form-control/

Comment: Nossa, a resposta estava na minha cara kk, obrigado